# Python 2.7 csv module only 498 items

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, spyder

Using Spyder (Python 2.7) I want to assemble a script that appends, reads and prints data from 73 sensors that is received weekly as .txt file. The output should be sorted by columns and easily addressable.

Input Sample:

```
"timestamp";"LT";"WW_DepthOfWater";...
"2019-01-21 00:00:29";"2019-01-01 19:56:05+00:00";"0.0";...
```

Each file contains 73 columns (of course) and 3348 rows (header + data).
So far I am trying to read just one column of a file but I only get the last 498 items from that column with the following code:

```
import csv
with open('1_20190121_00_amcs.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')

    timestamp = []
    #LT = []
    #WW_DepthOfWater = []


    for row in reader:
        timestamp = row[0]
        #LT = row[1]
        #WW_DepthOfWater = row[2]


        #timestamp.append(timestamp)
        #LT.append(LT)
        #WW_DepthOfWater.append(WW_DepthOfWater)


        print (timestamp)
        #print (LT)
        #print (WW_DepthOfWater)
```

If I print 2 columns (e.g. timestamp & LT) it gives the last 249 items for each of those columns, so still 498 total.

Output Sample:

```
2019-01-27 23:51:04
2019-01-01 19:46:50+00:00
2019-01-27 23:54:05
2019-01-01 19:49:51+00:00
2019-01-27 23:57:06
2019-01-01 19:52:52+00:00
```

Any assistance shall be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you seem to have a .txt file in input. What is the separator of this file? you have specified semicolon but is that good?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into pandas

Comment: Upload the input file to a public location so we can have a look

Comment: The separator was my first suspect too but that doesn't explain why I get a fixed number of items regardless of the number of printed columns. Here is the link to the sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4ihapqfsmy16re/1_20190121_00_amcs.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the solution, even if it's temporary:
In Spyder/Tools/Preferences/IPython console/Display tab/Source code I've set Buffer to maximum number of lines. This should work until I reach that number.
Still, if you have any suggestions regarding the task at hand please don't hesitate.